# Why is the "layout" option for the geometry package undefined?

Tags: margins, geometry

I am having problem while using `layout` options with `geometry` package,
I cannot seem to compile the `.tex` file.

With the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\geometry{paperwidth=10in,paperheight=6in,layout=a6paper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I am getting this error when compiling `.tex` with `pdflatex`

```
! Package keyval Error: layout undefined.
```

> 1. Please help me resolve this problem?
> 2. And how do I check if all options in the package are working.

I am using `MikTeX 2.8` on `Windows XP` and `WinEdt` IDE.

Comment: What version of `geometry` are you using? Find out by adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{article}`. This compiles without problem on TeX Live 2009 on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) (with `geometry` 2010/03/13 v5.3).

Comment: thanks a lot, it was older version, now I updated it to v5.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing the [obsolete geometry v4.2 manual](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) with the [manual of the current version 5.6](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf), it seems that the `layout` package option was introduced in version 5 (which was a major upgrade). Update your TeX distribution in order to get the current version of `geometry`, and everything should be fine. (I compiled your example, and it worked without problem.)

EDIT: Here are the links to: 1. [Latest version of geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for manual install; 2. [MiKTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup) for TeX distribution upgrade; 3. [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) for TeX distribution change.

Comment: It was an older version, updated it to v5.6, it's working now.
Thank you.